# Stub / Mock Zend Db in Zend Framework 2

Tags: php, mocking, phpunit, zend-framework2, stub

i'm trying to stub specific part of Zend Db.

```
$statement = $this->getAdapter()->createStatement();
$query->prepareStatement($this->getAdapter(), $statement);
```

So `$this->getAdapter()` is an instance of 
`Mock::getMock('Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter')`
And `$query` an instance of `Zend\Db\Sql\AbstractSql`.

How I can inject data in this $statement?

Regards,

Comment: My first question would be, why are you trying to mock a ZF2 class, and then where? At first glance, it seems like you may be trying to mock too much. Can you share more of your code, whether here or with a Gist link please?